# Is it appropriate and grammatically good to write 'It all began with one troubling news"?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns

I am struggling, for some reason, something tells me this sentence doesn't sound that natural? Is there a better way to say the same or is this sentence of mine is fine?

Comment: I think it is fine, and is commonly used.  Re, alternative sentences, there can be many.

Comment: In idiomatic U.S. English, the likelier wording would be "It all began with some troubling news" or perhaps "It all began with a bit of troubling news." A native English speaker in the U.S. would be very unlikely to say "It all began with one troubling news."

Comment: “Appropriate” depends on context.

Comment: @SvenYargs The same applies in British English, if you wanted to restrict it to something specific you'd say "It all began with one _piece_ of troubling news" or  "...one _item_ of troubling news"". News is a mass noun not a countable one, in fact it is less countable thanmass nouns like "sand" and "water" which are sometimes used as countable nouns.

Answer (score 0):

*news* is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun), like *air*; it effectively has no singular or plural.  You're looking for *one piece of news*, or *some news*.  (If you say *some news* I will take it to mean one piece of news unless you say more.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes I would use that, but my text has this introduction and it should be specifically about 'one piece of news' but this wording seems too cumbersome to me.

Comment: Use “one news story”

Comment: If I get news about my cousin from another cousin, I don't call it a “news story”.

Comment: @Xanne Or "one news _item_". Guy's writing won't  be accepted as correct by native speakers, even ones who don't know what a mass noun is, if he uses a mass noun as a count noun.

Comment: @boldben story is not a mass count noun

Comment: @Xanne I'm not saying it is, yours is a perfectly good suggestion to which I am offering an alternative. The rest of my comment related to the OP's suggestion that the correct form of words is too cumbersome so he needs to simplify it by treating a mass noun as a count noun. Perhaps I shouldn't make one comment do two unrelated things.